# Trigger AWS Lambda when at least x minutes have passed since last event of type y

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-cloudwatch

I have 2 AWS Lambda functions (`L1` and `L2`).  I'd like to trigger `L2` when it's been 5 minutes since the last time `L1` ran.

`L1` is triggered everyday starting around the same time from multiple sources in random sequences.  The timing and frequency of invocations varies from less than a second between invocations to 3 minutes between invocations over the course of a window ranging 5 to 45 minutes before all invocations of `L1` are finished.  It's safe to assume, `L1` won't be triggered again the same day if 5 minutes passes since the last invocation.

Right now, I use cron to trigger `L2` 1 hour after the first instance of `L1` is usually triggered, but the excess wait time is unnecessary and wasteful.

Is there a way to set up a timer based on events in Cloudwatch?  Every time L1 runs, the timer would reset and if the timer reaches 5 minutes, then trigger L2?

Maybe a way to reset a new cron schedule every time there's a certain Cloudwatch event?

I'm not sure how to do this, but someone else (offline) suggested that I could test for an existing scheduled event/cron job at the beginning of `L1`.  If it's present, then disable it before running the rest of `L1`.  Before ending the function, enable a new scheduled event/cron job for 5 minutes in the future.  Therefore, the scheduled event/cron job will constantly be reset each time `L1` is invoked.  I'm not sure how to implement this, but it sounds reasonable.  The only issue I see is dealing with overlapping `L1` invocations to avoid multiple scheduled events/cron jobs.

I realize this could be solved with an EC2 instance and a simple timer, but I'd prefer to stay serverless.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you can use [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to help you overcome this problem.

You could invoke your first Lambda function, then if you want a delay use a [wait state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html).

After this wait state you could then invoke the second Lambda function.

There are many complex flows you can build, and as per your request this is all serverless.

Here are some [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/create-sample-projects.html) to look at.